# MongoDB: Embedded or Normalized Data Models for Users and Activities

Tags: mongodb, database-design, model, database

I'm designing the models of my database for a new project and since I come from the SQL world I'm not sure which approach is better.

**This are my main relationships:**

- Activities organized by Users. (e.g.: John is organizing a Soccer
  game)
- Users who join Activities. (e.g.: Anna and Rob joined the Soccer game John has organized)
- Activities belong to a category/ActivityType (John's game belongs to the Soccer category)
- Users rate other users after completing the activity (e.g.: John rates Anna with 5 stars and Rob with 5 stars for their performance
  during the Soccer game).

**The pseudocode would be something like this:**

1. **User**

   - _id
   - fullname
   - email
   - password
   - loc ({ lon: X, lat: Y })
   - activities (Array of Activity)
   - average_rate
   - created_at
   - updated_at
2. **Rate**

   - _id
   - timestamp
   - activity (Activity)
   - rater_user (User)
   - rated_user (User)
   - created_at
   - updated_at
3. **ActivityType**

   - _id
   - name
   - radius
4. **Activity**

   - _id
   - type (ActivityType)
   - organizer (User)
   - loc ({ lon: X, lat: Y })
   - address
   - time
   - max_participants
   - description
   - participants (Array of User)
   - requests (Array of User)
   - created_at
   - updated_at

Should I moved from this normalized approach to embedded data models?

Comment: What would you be embedding?

Comment: Rate and ActivityType in Activity for example. But I want to be able to get a list of all the available ActivityType items or calculate the average rate of a user and that makes me thing of a more normalized approach.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an answer about embedding or reference in `mongodb` I wrote. It's highly recommended.

[MongoDB for BI use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392285/mongodb-for-bi-use/26394791#26394791)

Embedding is better for :

> - Small subdocuments
> - Data that does not change regularly
> - When eventual consistency is acceptable
> - Document that grow by a small amount
> - Data that you'll often need to perform asecond query to fetch
> - Fast reading speed

References are better for

> - Large subdocuments
> - Volatile data
> - When immediate consistency is necessary
> - Document grow with a large amount
> - Data that you often exclude from document
> - Fast write speed

-From 《Mongodb Definitive Guide》

Answer (score 0):

It depends to deleting, updating and types of query you are gonna need.

- For not embedding design you should run some **Join Like** query for
  retrieve data and it requires random in hard drive and it takes some
  extra time
- MongoDb is growing only database (in size) means deleting a document will not
  decrease size of database (and file system) and so many deleting operations will lead
  to data fragmentation. If you update a document with bigger document
  mongo will delete the document and insert it some other place and 
  you have same fragmentation problem in deleting a document, In embedding system you have to deal
  with more fragmentation problem
- ...

I recommend for you to read book `Mongodb Applied Design Patterns`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @Disposer. Will do!