# When should we use embedded documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I read a lot about embedding in MongoDB, but still I don't know when to use it. I thought of some scenarios:

I have A collection named UserGroups with these fields:

- **_id**
- **name**

Now I want to add an user to Users collection:

1. I should have a **groupName** field in Users collection and update it when UserGroups collection gets an update.
2. I should add the **groupId** field in Users collection and perform a join whenever I want the UserGroups.name.
3. I should add the user document as an embedded document to UserGroups collection.
4. Or I should add the userGroup document as an embedded document in Users collection. though, I don't think I should do it.

Which option should I use?

Comment: There's no objectively right answer to give. You have to consider the way you query content, as well as the fact that embedded documents, when stored in an array, could eventually exceed the size of a document (or create a very large, unwieldy document).

Comment: @DavidMakogon, so I should always use the referenced collections?

Comment: MongoDB is designed to be schema-less for the very purpose of being flexible in this respect. Usually, if you have one-to-many relation and you don't intend to change sub-objects on their own later, just put them as embedded property of the stored object. In this particular case, I'd personally go with having a separate collection of user groups but it's just a matter of personal preference and potential queries that you might have in near future.

Comment: Some relevant reading [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414844/mongodb-embedded-or-normalized-data-models-for-users-and-activities).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Due to MongoDB schema flexibility, developers no longer have to design the database schema first i.e. [Entity Relationship Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). The design of the application comes first, then design the database schema to match the application usage (query, writes, updates, etc). See also [Data Modelling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/).

This is the reason why there is no right/wrong answer on the database schema design. There are various use case for MongoDB, and different applications can leverage different models.

> When should we use embedded documents in MongoDB?

Without knowing exactly how your applications will interact with the data, the following answer is only a *general guidelines or approach* :

**Favour the embedding, unless there is a reason not to.**

Try to denormalise `UserGroup` into `User` first. For example:

```
{ userid: 1001,
  name: "Reza Tayebi", 
  group: {id: 10,
          name: "Developer"
  }
}
```

**When the relationship is one to few (not many, not unlimited).**

The above example is applicable, if a user can either be in one or few groups. If there are more than one but limited to under 5, you may introduce an array. However if a user can be in 20+ or an unlimited number of groups, you should start considering separating groups into another collection.

**When retrieval is likely to happen together.**

If the retrieval of `UserGroups` is always associated with a user. For example, either `Query some users with their respective groups`, or `Query some users given a specific group(s)`.

**When updates are likely to happen at the same time.**

If it is likely that you would update `Users` and `UserGroups` at the same time.
Although starting from MongoDB 4.0, you can use [multi-documents transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) if `Users` and `UserGroups` are not embedded, a single document transaction would be more performant. See also [Atomicity and Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).

**When the field is rarely updated.**

If the name of a group is rarely updated in the collection. For example, if the group name `Developers` required to be updated to `Web Developers` for the entire `Users` collection often, then embedding `UserGroups` is not suitable.

Again, above are only general guidelines that you should consider before designing your schema, see also the following resources:

- [Blog: 6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design Part 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), [Part 2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2), and [Part 3](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)
- [Data Model Examples and Patterns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/)
- [Operational Factors and Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-operations/)
- [Hybrid Schema Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/#hybrid-schema-design)

UPDATE:

A new resource: [Building with Patterns: A Summary](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary). Also worth mentioning, for situations that require atomicity of reads and writes to multiple documents (in a single or multiple collections), MongoDB supports [multi-document Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/).

Comment: The Blog link was very insightful, but hasn't been updated to include mongodb transactions which guarantee atomic updates across multiple documents: [check the article here](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/acid-transactions)